# Better Tab-Tab experience for file-completion if directory is big (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, tab-completion

In `~/tmp/` I store some files while working on the command line.

```
❯ ls ~/tmp/ [TAB-TAB]

Display all 119 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Usualy I want to work on a file which has recent ctime.

Is there a way to enhance the bash-shell, so that I get a list of the recent files of this directory, so that I can easily choose the file which I copied there just some seconds ago?

For example after hitting TAB-TAB I would like to see a list of the 10 most recent files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is possible in bash, but it can be
[configured in zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dsort_002c-completion-style)
with something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort date
```

(you can also change the line such that this style is only used for certain file name patterns)

[`zsh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)
is very similar to bash, can even be called a superset of it.